# Do we still need HMAC now that SHA3 is here?

Tags: hmac, mac, sha-3

In [Another look at HMAC](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/074) from Koblitz and Menezes, they state that HMAC came along because doing h(secret || message) was vulnerable to length extension attacks. But as far as I know, these kind of attacks only exist because of the Merkle-Damgard construction.

Now that we have SHA-3, that does not use such a construction, and that is not vulnerable to length extension attacks. Do we need to use the complicated HMAC-SHA3 or can we just use SHA3 as a MAC?